# Change DateTime .addDays to .addMonths using switch/if (dropdown driven)

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to use dropdown control to change the add interval. (Days,Months,Years). Cant see the solution yet other than surrounding all of the code below with an if or switch.

Here is my code currently:

```
for(var x = this.dtpStartDate.Value; x <= this.dtpEndDate.Value; x = x.AddDays(1)))
{
  // 
}
```

What I've tried so far was to introduce a variable for .addDays(n) but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Most of the code here looks like it's not relevant to what you're trying to do - but we don't know what the dropdown control is or anything like that at the moment. Could you rewrite this as a [mcve]? (I suspect you'd be able to rewrite it as a console app that just writes the appropriate output to the console based on some string input - that should be easy enough to convert to a non-console app later, and console apps are easier to present in a complete form.)

Comment: consider creating a function with a case statement

Comment: Im trying to avoid duplicating the complete for loop in an if or switch statement and so far have struck out simply replacing the .addDay Method with .addYears method in a switch statement.

Comment: Maybe something like `Func<DateTime, int, DateTime> addX = condition ? (x, i) => x.AddDays(i) : (x, i) => x.AddMonths(i);` could give you an idea. Although I think assigning lambdas in a ternary statement doesn't work that easily. (Can't verify right now) -- DropDown suggest that a `switch` would be more appropriate than `? :`, anyways.

Comment: Im incorporating your potential solution now Corak. Ill report back.